# asp net mvc prevent-stop closing of jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How to stop closing the pop-up that is in javascript after submit

When I click on Save they insert into SQL and dialog closes. How can I accomplish this without closing the dialog?

index.cshtm

```
 $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
               title: 'name',
               autoOpen: false,
               resizable: true,
               height:550,
                 width: 658,
                 maxHeight: 865,
                 maxWidth: 658,
               show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
               modal: true,
               draggable: true,
               open: function (event, ui) {
                   $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                   $(this).load(url);
               }
           });
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Insert()
{
    return View();
}
```

ViewModel

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "infoForm" })) 
{  
    @(Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.name))</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="Submit" onclick="hideshow()"/>  
}
```

Comment: Your question need to be more clear. Maybe use a couple more sentences and punctuation?

Comment: Is your form inside the dialog?

Comment: Form is separacion, Just give me a plain example

how not to close the pop-up that was created in JavaScript after Submit